# How do i get the 10 public keys where the amount is > 100

Tags: solana-program, web3.js, solana-wallet-adapter

```
import { Connection, PublicKey, LAMPORTS_PER_SOL } from "@solana/web3.js";


const publicKeyString = "Gjkud8j4qDLRyox4eMGC5QDWq9HoG5JTYpxRjLYepHyh";
const mainnetBetaEndpoint = "https://api.mainnet-beta.solana.com";
const connection = new Connection(mainnetBetaEndpoint);

(async () => {
  try {
    const balance = await connection.getBalance(new PublicKey(publicKeyString));
    console.log("SOL Balance:", balance / LAMPORTS_PER_SOL);
  } catch (error) {
    console.error("Error fetching balance:", error);
  }
})();
```

this is how i can get the total sol balance of the wallet with public key
now lets say i dont know the public key but i want to get the first(latest) 100 public key where sol blance is > 100

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by "first" or "latest"?

If you mean the most recently used pubkeys with more than 100 SOL, you'll need to fetch blocks with `getBlock`, iterate through all transactions, and pick out all the addresses that match your criteria.

There may be bespoke indexing solutions out there to return this data, but using the normal RPC calls, you'll need to sift through the data yourself.